# Azure Stream Analytics job - How to remotely deploy/send reference data file on the edge

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-edge

I'm planning to use Azure Stream Analytics on the edge and I want to be able to look-up some data from file i.e. use a reference data input.

Of course, my look-up data is static and slowly changing, but I want to be able to remotely send/deploy this file.

How should I do that? I can't find any useful info on the net about this.

- Is it possible to automate this with IoT Hub and/or template deployments?
- Is it possible to include this file in the docker image of the ASA job that is being deployed on the Edge run-time via IoT Hub Edge Deployment functionality?
- Is there some Azure API that could be used?

Actually, this is very well supported and [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data#tips-on-refreshing-your-reference-data) for an ASA Job running in the cloud. I want to achieve the same, but on the Edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- At this time, the use of reference data in ASA jobs on IoT Edge is not automated, you will need to create a local reference data file first on the host based on query, and configure the data type as reference data and path as volume/path/to/.txt (linux) Disk:/path/to/.txt (windows), when creating an edge job.
- We do not support storing the file in the docker image of ASA job. The only data source for reference data is local file.
- There is no Azure API to be used for deploying the reference data. Once user triggers an ASA job update through IoT Edge deployment, reference data location will be updated

You can find more information on our [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-edge) of ASA on IoT Edge. Any customer feedback is welcomed, and we would love to explore new features that would be helpful for users.